# How to Insert a value to table using stored procedure which is having foreign key as one of the column

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Created the table using this

```
CREATE TABLE Appointment
(
    AppointmentNumber INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    PatientID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Patient(PatientID),
    AppointmentDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
    ReminderRequired BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0),
    ReasonForVisit VARCHAR(150)
)
GO
```

Created stored procedure using

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddAppointment
    (
    @PatID INT,
    @AppDate DATETIME,
    @RemRequired BIT,
    @ReaForVisit VARCHAR(150)
    )
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Appointment ON

INSERT INTO dbo.Appointment
           ([PatientID],[AppointmentDate],[ReminderRequired],[ReasonForVisit])
     VALUES
           (@PatID,@AppDate,@RemRequired,@ReaForVisit)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Appointment ON
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
END 
GO
```

Executing Stored Procedure using

```
EXECUTE AddAppointment
    @PatID='2',
    @AppDate='1999-09-09',
    @RemRequired=1,
    @ReaForVisit='hahahahaha'
GO
```

The result is: Command Completed successfully

But there is no new entry in the table when I run

```
SELECT * FROM Appointment
```

PLEASE HELP

Comment: Why are you surpressing the error in the event of one in your `TRY...CATCH`? The reason you don't know what's going wrong it because you aren't `THROW`ing the error, you're just ignoring/surpressing it and pretending "everything is fine". `THROW` the error, find out what's wrong.

Comment: There is an inconsistency: in the table Appointment you haven't got an identity-column, but in the SP you have written  SET IDENTITY_INSERT Appointment ON

Answer (score 2):

`AppointmentNumber` is declared to be `NOT NULL`, but you haven't provided a value.  Hence, the `INSERT` fails.  If you showed the error in the `CATCH` block, this would probably be obvious.

Presumably, you want it assigned automatically, so make it an identity column:

```
AppointmentNumber INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
```

Also, there should be no reason to set `IDENTITY_INSERT` to `ON` in your stored procedure.  That should be the default value.

You might have a secondary problem if `PatientId` does not properly refer to a valid patient.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the "Command Completed successfully" is because it did. In the event of an error, you've told SQL Server to `ROLLBACK` the transaction, and then move on; don't generate an error, don't tell the user about said error, do not pass GO, do not collect £200. `THROW` the error in the `TRY...CATCH` and it'll tell you what the error is:

```sql
...
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        THROW;
END CATCH;
```

As Gordon has then mentioned in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66102580/2029983), This will tell you that you're trying to either set `IDENTITY_INSERT` to `ON` on a table that doesn't have an `IDENTITY`, or you're trying to `INSERT` a `NULL` value into a column that doesn't allow them.

Comment: Thank You Bro, I added THROW also.